# Crystal Report Cross Tab Custom Total

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Scenario is,

I want to make cross tab crystal report like below image
[image: Check Image]

I made cross tab report shown below but it showing obtain marks total only, I want proper percentage at end ((ObtainMarks/TotalMarks)*100)
[image]
help me to sort out pls. im new to corss tab. Its my 4th day on seraching about this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my Issue on SCN Forum at
http://scn.sap.com/thread/3871853

.@Siva's Answer is start point to solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to use calculated member to achieve this.

Go to preview on last column right `click --> calculated member --> insert`

You will get a new column added and in that edit the formula for the column and write your formula

Comment: as Im using WebServices, and making report for client side and dont need any DB connection.So I have no Sample data at design time. My Preview tab showing empty cross tab rectangle. So cant find Calculated member option. Tell me how to do now :(

Comment: Can you post how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

@Siva this is my Preview Tab for  Report, It showing empty Cross tab options.
Dataset for this report is made in Visual studio. I Select that Dataset as ADO.NET(XML) 
[image: Check Image]

Comment: you need to get atleast total column that is also mising check whether you can supressed the total column.. if it is supressed then first unsupress and then add calculated member

Comment: @Siva its not supressed, I Inserted cross tab again but still empty rectagnle in preview tab  but it shows columns in Design tab

Comment: @Siva, When I Remove all teh columns column.,row column, an Summary column from Cross Tab Expert then it shows only Total Column in preview tab, then I right Clicked on total header it shows "Calculation Member"> "Select Grand Total as first Value", but it does not show Insert child etc type option

Comment: I am using cr 2008 in that it shows what version you are using

Comment: It Crystal Report 2013 I think, Im new to Crystal reports

Comment: SAP Crystal Reports 2013

Comment: @Siva. It shows When use local DB connection Instead of .NET DataSet. But i dont want DB connection as My Reports are for webservices. Reports will be on client side